# How can I update axvline using a timer?

Tags: python, timer, pyqt

I would like to use PyQt5 to animate a plot, so that a vertical line scrolls across my figure over time.
In order to achieve this, I started modifying the code example provided in [this neat LearnPyQt tutorial](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/graphics-plotting/plotting-matplotlib/).
So far, I was able to plot a single vertical line at a user-defined abscissa using:

```
self.canvas.axes.axvline(x=5)
```

If I was using a `for` loop, I would simply update x based on the index, but in this case, I cannot figure how to update x based on the timer ID. How can I recover this value and pass it into my `update_plot` function?

Here is my code so far:

```
 import sys
 import random
 import matplotlib
 matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
 import pdb
 
 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
 
 from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
 from matplotlib.figure import Figure
 
 
 class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
 
     def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
         fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
         self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
         super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)
 
 
 class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
 
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
 
         self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
         self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
         self.timer_id = 0
         n_data = 50
         self.xdata = list(range(n_data))
         self.ydata = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(n_data)]
         self.update_plot()
 
         self.show()
 

         self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
         self.timer.setInterval(100)
 
         self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot)
         self.timer.start()
 
     def update_plot(self):
 
         self.canvas.axes.plot(self.xdata, self.ydata, 'r')
         self.canvas.axes.axvline(x=5)
         self.canvas.draw()
 
 
 app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
 w = MainWindow()
 app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep a reference to the axvline (Line2D object) then you can call `set_xdata` and increment `self.timer_id` when `update_plot` is called to move the line along the figure.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
        self.timer_id = 0
        n_data = 50
        self.xdata = list(range(n_data))
        self.ydata = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(n_data)]
        self.update_plot()

        self.show()


        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(100)

        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.timer.start()

    def update_plot(self):
        if not self.timer_id:
            self.canvas.axes.plot(self.xdata, self.ydata, 'r')
            self.vline = self.canvas.axes.axvline(x=self.timer_id)
        else:
            self.vline.set_xdata(self.timer_id)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.timer_id += 1
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot, Alec! I guess I overthought the problem: I was thinking of somehow retrieving time information from the `timer` method, while creating a `timer_id` and incrementing it was the most straightforward way to go. Thanks again!